# Компоненты и память

Tags: .net, c#

Если мы удаляем визуальный компонент подобным образом:

```
this.Controls.Remove(Label1)
```

, то память что под него выделялась освобождается? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удаляется ссылка на `Label1` в коллекции `Controls`. Когда все ссылки на `Label1` удалятся, то `Label1` станет кандидатом на удаление из памяти как объект, и [сборщик мусора](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) когда-нибудь доберётся до него

Comment: Не подкинешь норм материалов почитать о сборщике мусора для C#? Я де-то читал что им можно управлять, мб Я ошибаюсь...

Comment: Кстати, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Не специалист по gc. Но знаю, что материалов в открытом доступе много, и Вы быстро найдёте информацию. Так что у меня только такая ссылка http://www.google.ru/search?q=garbage+collection+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t :)